# Event that listens for enter click gets called only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

am trying to dynamically add text to textarea when enter is hit.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#content').on("keydown", function (e) {

        if (e.keyCode == 13) {

            $('textarea').append("Hello");
        }
    })
});
```

This is the code that runs and it only adds text once (for the first time after page load) and then nothing. What could be causing this?

Comment: Can you share a demo? jsfiddle or something similar.

Comment: For me, in a minimal sample based on your code, it works as many times as I want. Please give the whole context.

Comment: textarea are form elements, if you want to add content, use it's value. `$('textarea')[0].value+= 'Hello';`

Comment: @nhrnjic6: One question : If you reload also, the textarea should contain "hello", right?

Comment: text is gone on reload, well I just have one textarea element nothing special

Comment: @Mistic thanks I get that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('textarea').on("keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            this.value+= 'Hello';
        }
    })
});
```

The event is registred on the textarea itself and the new content is added to the textarea value.

Answer (score 0):

**add text to textarea**

If you want to add text to **any place** in existing content in your textarea you could use this function. Just click on the place do you want the text to be inserted, and in your case hit enter. But you can use it for any event you like (e.g. button click).

```
function insertText(inputId, text) {
    var txtarea = document.getElementById(inputId);
    var scrollPos = txtarea.scrollTop;
    var strPos = 0;
    var br = ((txtarea.selectionStart || txtarea.selectionStart == '0') ?
        "ff" : (document.selection ? "ie" : false));
    if(br == "ie") {
        txtarea.focus();
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.moveStart('character', -txtarea.value.length);
        strPos = range.text.length;
    } else if(br == "ff") strPos = txtarea.selectionStart;

    var front = (txtarea.value).substring(0, strPos);
    var back = (txtarea.value).substring(strPos, txtarea.value.length);
    txtarea.value = front + text + back;
    strPos = strPos + text.length;
    if(br == "ie") {
        txtarea.focus();
        var range = document.selection.createRange();
        range.moveStart('character', -txtarea.value.length);
        range.moveStart('character', strPos);
        range.moveEnd('character', 0);
        range.select();
    } else if(br == "ff") {
        txtarea.selectionStart = strPos;
        txtarea.selectionEnd = strPos;
        txtarea.focus();
    }
    txtarea.scrollTop = scrollPos;
    return false;
}
```

Here is the edited fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/zLy2yzyd/

Comment: Op want's to add content to the textarea, not modify #content -- edit: my mistake, I read "container" and not "content"